# Apache Flink: Infer schema of a CSV file like Spark

Tags: apache-flink, flink-sql

In Spark we can use infer schema to dynamically read schema from file e.g.:

```
df = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').options(delimiter='|',header='true', inferschema='true').load('cars.csv')
```

Is there a way to do same in Flink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flink has no built-in support for automatic schema inference from CSV files.

You could implement such functionality on top by analyzing the first rows of a CSV file and generating a corresponding CsvTableSource.

Comment: Is there a way to use external catalog for this

Comment: Yes, but you still have to implement the schema inference yourself. You can also implement a custom TableSource, that infers the schema of a CSV file.

Comment: As per my current research i have to add a class file as per csv format.So if no of columns in csv increase or decrease i have to update the class file as well and for that i have to compile my code again .Plz correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: This is only true if you hardcode the schema in the Flink job. You can also passing the schema as a parameter to your Flink job. Then you don't need to update the code.

Comment: Plz refer some tutorial,blog or github link with this kind of code.

Comment: The schema inference can be done on-the-fly, incrementally, until enough number of rows is read which succesfully identify the data types for all columns. In order to do that, the schema inference logic has to delay the production of data to downstream until all columns are inferred, or the upstram closes, or memory is full, or some other exception.